# Swift Base64 string is leaking memory

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks

According to Instruments my iOS app is leaking memory.
[image: Instruments]

I have been searching what this causes and apparently Swift doesn't like a base64 string of 25000 characters. When I run

`leaks Application`

In the command line I receive the following error:

`Leak: 0x7fd8a510b600  size=25088  zone: MallocHelperZone_0x11cc7a000   CFString  ObjC  CoreFoundation  length: 24708`

I use the following code to turn a base64 string into an UIImage:

```js
// MARK: Initialization
init?(id: Int, name: String, logo: Any) {

    self.id = id
    self.name = name

    if logo is String  {
        var logo = logo as! String

        // Swift can't handle the data:image/png;base64, part of the base64 string so we remove it
        if let range = logo.rangeOfString(";base64,", range: logo.startIndex..<logo.endIndex)  {
            logo.removeRange(logo.startIndex..<range.endIndex)

            // Lets turn it into an UIImage
            let imageData = NSData(base64EncodedString: logo, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))

            if imageData != nil {
                self.logo = UIImage(data: imageData!)!
            }
        }
    } else if logo is UIImage {
        self.logo = logo as? UIImage
    } else {
        self.logo = UIImage()
    }

    super.init()
}
```

Does anyone has an idea how i can solve this problem?

Comment: I have been struggling with a similar problem for the past week...

Answer (score 1):

Apparently removing a range of string with the `rangeOfString` function was the problem. The `rangeOfString` function can't handle a string that 'big'.

I found the problem through Instruments by clicking on Details > Call Trees and then I saw where the problem in my own code was. I refactored the code to regex:

```
// Swift can't handle the data:image/png;base64, part of the base64 string so we remove it
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "data:([\\w]+/[\\w]+);base64,", options: [])
let base64 = regex.stringByReplacingMatchesInString(logo, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, logo.characters.count), withTemplate: "")
```

Comment: This is all unnecessary. Simply do `let url = URL(string: logo)` then `let data = Data(contentsOf: url`. `URL` easily handles `data:` URLs.